# tibbletime with tq_transmute producing strange error, column obviously exists but says it doesn't

Tags: r, tidyquant, tibbletime

I could have sworn this code worked a week ago, but I guess that I am mistaken. I keep getting the error: Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `asset` doesn't exist.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
In addition: Warning message:
`...` must not be empty for ungrouped data frames.
Did you want `data = everything()`?

I've taken it step by step to try and see where it is in my code and I can tell that it is after I group the assets, and occurs when I start to add on the tq_transmute. If someone could please help that would be greatly appreciated. I will have code that you should be able to just run automatically and see what I am talking about. It doesn't make any sense because "asset" does exist after gathering the data and grouping it.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate) 
library(readxl)
library(highcharter) 
library(tidyquant) 
library(timetk) 
library(tibbletime) 
library(quantmod) 
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(scales)
library(magrittr)
library(broom)
library(purrr)

symbols <- c("SPY", "EFA", "IJS", "EEM", "AGG")

prices <- getSymbols(symbols,
                     src = 'yahoo',
                     from = "2012-12-31",
                     to = "2017-12-31",
                     auto.assign = TRUE,
                     warnings = FALSE) %>%
  map(~Ad(get(.)))%>% #the period here in get(.) refers to our intial object
  reduce(merge) %>%
  `colnames<-`(symbols)


# WHERE MY PROBLEM OCCURS 
asset_returns_tbltime <-
  prices %>% 
  tk_tbl(preserve_index = TRUE,
                    rename_index = "date")%>%
  # this is the the tibbletime function
  as_tbl_time(index = date) %>% 
  as_period(period = "month",
            side = "end") %>%
  gather(asset, returns, -date) %>%
  group_by(asset) %>% 
  tq_transmute(mutate_fun = periodReturn, #GETTING THE ERROR SOMEWHERE IN HERE
                                   type = "log") %>%
  spread(asset, monthly.returns) %>%
  select(date, symbols) %>%
  slice(-1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gather` has been replaced with `pivot_longer` and `spread` with `pivot_wider`. If you change `gather` code to `pivot_longer` it works. I am not exactly sure why it fails with `gather` though.

```
prices %>% 
  tk_tbl(preserve_index = TRUE,
         rename_index = "date")%>%
  as_tbl_time(index = date) %>% 
  as_period(period = "month",
            side = "end") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -date, names_to = 'asset', values_to = 'returns') %>%
  group_by(asset) %>%
  tq_transmute(mutate_fun = periodReturn, type = "log")  %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = asset, values_from = monthly.returns) %>%
  select(date, symbols) %>%
  slice(-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate it. It was driving me insane.